# window.alert change title in gwt

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt2

when **

> Window.alert

** is used in gwt, a window pops up with the message , I want to **

> change the title

** of that window , Please help as I need it urgently

Answer (score 0):

Window.alert() opens a native dialog box which contais OK button. You can not change the title of it.

Use [PopupPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html) or [DecoratedPopupPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DecoratedPopupPanel.html) or [DialogBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DialogBox.html)

Comment: how to add the contents to dialogBox , i created a label and added it to dialogBox , then i added a button- its throwing an exception

Comment: Use layout panel. i.e. VerticlePanel, HorizonatalPanel..etc. put widgets in it. and finally add this layout with widgets group in dialog. because only one widgets you allow to put in dialogbox.

Comment: @Ekata, If you find this answer useful then you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You cant change the title of that ..for that you need to look into another alternative ..

Below is one of them.

Here is a simple dialog box which is genreated from GWT sample code

```
// Create the popup dialog box
    final DialogBox dialogBox = new DialogBox();
    dialogBox.setText("Remote Procedure Call");
    dialogBox.setAnimationEnabled(true);
    final Button closeButton = new Button("Close");
    // We can set the id of a widget by accessing its Element
    closeButton.getElement().setId("closeButton");
    final Label textToServerLabel = new Label();
    final HTML serverResponseLabel = new HTML();
    VerticalPanel dialogVPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    dialogVPanel.addStyleName("dialogVPanel");
    dialogVPanel.add(new HTML("<b>Sending name to the server:</b>"));
    dialogVPanel.add(textToServerLabel);
    dialogVPanel.add(new HTML("<br><b>Server replies:</b>"));
    dialogVPanel.add(serverResponseLabel);
    dialogVPanel.setHorizontalAlignment(VerticalPanel.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    dialogVPanel.add(closeButton);
    dialogBox.setWidget(dialogVPanel);
```

Add your lables and widgets in middle to get the desired dialog ..